# Nightmarejs hangs and does not proceed after "did-get-response-details"

Tags: web-scraping, nightmare

So I am running Nightmarejs to do web scraping. On some URLs it just hangs. Meaning it does not proceed after emitting 'did-get-response-details'. It doesnt emit any failed to load events and doesnt timeout. I am not able to find any related issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is that u get for using a library called nightmarejs....  I would post this question in https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare